# Difference between the kanjis for "tears/なみだ": 涙 and 泪

Tags: kanji

I found [here](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1011231410) that 涙 is a semasio-phonetic character (形声文字) while 泪 is a more visual version. Apart from that no big differences should be between this two ways of writing "namida". Anyway I would like to be sure of that.

Thank you very much!

Edit: I searched 泪 on google. Although the results are mostly in Chinese there are also results in Japanese. See for example [here](https://www.google.de/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=%22%C3%BCbervoriger%20WOche%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=ZzPfVoOtFKeI8Qen7Z4I#q=%E6%B3%AA%20%E3%81%AF&channel=fs&start=20).

Comment: The difference is you will never see the latter in Japanese.  Your first hint should be a google search which returns pages and pages of Chinese.

Comment: thank you for your comment. Actually I searched it on google. If you do a quick search with a hiragana on it you will see that it is used in japanese as well.

Comment: @kiss-o-matic But I have seen 泪 in Japanese, more than once.  It's definitely much less *frequent*, however.

Comment: "never" was a bit of an exaggeration and I admit, it's lost in the nature of message boards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

涙 is 常用漢字 but 泪 is not. Today 泪 is only seen in lyrics, poetry and such. One answer in the chiebukuro question you linked says 「泪の方が演歌っぽい」, which I think best describes the actual difference in usage.

Answer (score 1):

There is apparently also a third character for this reading, 涕.  I'm not aware of any differences in meaning between the three, but in my own reading, I've only ever run across the 涙 spelling.

**UPDATE:**

Be sure to read the comments from snailboat -- the additional data should paint a clearer picture of the relative occurrences of these different spellings.

Comment: In various web-based corpora, I found that the ratio is something like 100:1 for 涙 to 泪, and 1000:1 for 涙 to 涕, but I'd actually expect those ratios to be greater if they only included modern usage.  I think the corpus results must also include some pre-war orthography.  Personally, I've only seen 泪 a few times, I think mostly in song titles and lyrics where people are deliberately using the "non-standard" choice of kanji, but I *think* I've seen it in fiction writing at least once.  (I didn't put it in my notes, so I'm not sure.)

Comment: Useful additional data, thank you @snailboat!